# External Menu for Website

Tags: html, css, menu

How would I go about creating a menu (complex, simple, etc - doesn't matter in this example) and then linking to each in each page of my site?

I wish to create `menu` and then have `index.htm`, `page2.htm`, `page3.htm`, .. `pageN.htm` refer to it and load it as if it exists on each page individually.

Basically, I wish to write it once, and use it everywhere.

For example:

```
Menu:

Home | Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page N
```

And then:

```
Page1.htm

Home | Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page N

Content
More Content
Even More Content
```

...and...

```
Page2.htm

Home | Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page N

Content
More Content
Even More Content
```

...and so forth so that when I change the content of the menu, it will reflect automatically across each page that references it, much the same was that CSS works.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using any form of server side communications (.NET/PHP/CF etc)?

Comment: No, I am not.  I am using CSS with HTML where all files reside within the same directory (or sub-directory/ies).

Comment: Well, this might be possible with some nifty javascript, but I'm not sure, otherwise see if your webserver supports SSI (.shtml), if it does you can include external HTML (your menu) into each page. The preferred alternative as I see it though is to either use PHP or .NET or any other server side tech and include it in that way.

Comment: The only way I've found to include docs with JavaScript is if your external file is an awful lot of `document.write("..");`s. I suppose you may be able to set your JS file as a set of variables which when printed make up your menu (or one var would work, but arrays may be nicer). Regardless, server side seems the best option if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/Paste. :)

Seriously, I did HTML/CSS only dev for a year or two and the only reliable way I found was copy/paste the menu. Now, if you go into PHP at all, heck even one line of PHP you can `include` an HTML file (here, your menu) which is saved in a separate menu.html file.

It's a lot of work to keep the menus up to date, especially if you have a lot of pages - that's why so many people switched to a Content Management System (CMS) like Joomla/Wordpress/Drupal, or added PHP, or even Dreamweaver does it (library items).

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline ul with a tags inside the lis linking to the other pages(maybe explaining it bad

```
<ul
   <li class ="current_page" ><a href="someUrl1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="someUrl2">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

etc etc